# Clone a quote and mantain the relationship with its original quote line items

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom, quote, quotelineitem

I'm trying to make a button which clones the quote and keeps the relationship with the original QuoteLineItem.
Basically I don't know how to clone related lists. I get the quote Id from the page with `ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');` Then I query the fields I need to duplicate,filtered by the quote id. When I click the button it generates a quote without QuoteLineItems I've already tried with `clone(false,true);` method, but it doesn't work. I hope it's clear enough. Thanks in advance
P.S. Of course I created a custom button with the extension

Comment: I'm fairly certain QuoteLineItems point to a Quote and not the other way around. You'll not only need to clone the Quote, but also re-parent the QuoteLineItems that already exist (or clone those and point them at the new Quote).

Comment: I tried but  the quotelineitem field"quoteId"  is not writable. I can't allow reparenting so I don't know what to do :(

Comment: If you can't allow re-parenting and you don't want to keep the old QOLs on the old Quote, you'll need to copy the QOL fields into new QOLs and delete the old ones.